How to Install Java 16 on Ubuntu 22.04?
I want to install java 16 on a V-server running ubuntu 22.04 but i cant find a way to install java 16 since it is an outdated version.

Run a VM of a version of Ubuntu that can use that version is one way.

Does this answer your question? How to install Java 8 in Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit?
